# Can you obtain the "Stack the Deck" and "Extra Credit" burn cards?

Tags: titanfall

Can you actually get these cards, and if you can, how? I've played through one generation, and neither me or my peers have seen them. Do you have to reach a certain point in the game? Have they been removed from the game?

According to this site, http://titanfall.wikia.com/wiki/Burn_Card , you can get them.
***Stack the deck*** *is apparently also known as* **Choose a Burn Card.**

Comment: I'm currently on Gen 4 and haven't seen either of those. :(

Comment: @Fluttershy By the looks of them, they could be very high level cards.

Comment: @peper757 - It sounds like the cards in question are rare.

Comment: I've never come across those cards either, nor as anyone I spoke to. Perhaps they were cards that were removed but left in the code?

Comment: @Rapitor Prehaps, but would be possible to obtain the pictures of them? (I don't know much about acsessing a game's code, but wouldn't Origin prevent you acsessing the code? I know that it can't be done on Xbox 1)

Comment: @peper757 during the beta before the game launched people got into the game's code and leaked pretty much every last bit of info that was in the full game. It's very possible for something to be 'finished' with art assets and all only to be cut out last minute for balancing reasons, free 1k xp doesnt really have the same "burn effect" or follow the one life rule and the ability to choose any card from your deck is quite ridiculously powerful. So I wouldn't be surprised that they were both removed.

Comment: @Rapitor Best explanation I've heard so far, but I'm still not sure if that's the case.